# Given $B \cup A = B$ and probability and set theory axioms, prove $\mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(B)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is less than or equal to $\mathbb{P}(B)$ using only this three things:

1. $B \cup A = B$
2. The three axioms of probability:

   a) $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is greater or equal to $0$.

   b) $\mathbb{P}(S) = 1$.

   c) If $A, B$ are disjoint (or mutually disjoint) then $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)$.
3. The ten laws of set theory (ex. domination law, identity law, de morgan's law, etc..)

I forgot to include this statement in the question: The proof must involve equations using only the symbols A, B, S, Pr, 0, U, n ( "and" in set theory), " , ( , ) and =. Hint: try to apply Axiom (c) to the set (B n notA) U A. Simplify this expression using the laws and apply Axiom (a)

I started with a statement that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is less than or equal to $\mathbb{P}(B)$ because $B \cup A = B$ (so $B$ is greater or equal to $\mathbb{P}(A)$. Then I'm stuck.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: [Proof that $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow A \cup B = B$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456377/proof-that-a-subseteq-b-leftrightarrow-a-cup-b-b) and [Proof that $A\subseteq B\implies\Bbb P(A) \le\Bbb P(B)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523413/proof-that-a-subseteq-b-implies-bbb-pa-le-bbb-pb)

Answer (score 3):

$B \cup A=B$ means that $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Now we will "disjointify":

Let $C=B - A$.

Then $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, and $A \cup C=B$.

So, $P(B)=P(A \cup C)=P(A)+P(C) \geq P(A)$ as $P(C) \geq 0$

Comment: @learnmore: because $A$ and $B$ aren't disjoint, so $P(A \cup B) \neq P(A)+P(B)$